# Form input validation, only permit values existing in another table - Acess

Tags: forms, validation, ms-access

I'm trying to create a data entry form in Access (2016) & wish to only permit values if they already exist in the product database.

My desired end result would be similar to the below:

User inputs: B8631
I would like Access to lookup that input value against Item_Master.Primal_Code and only permit it as a value if it exists already, rejecting it if it doesn't.

Comment: If the item master table is not too large (say about 2000 rows tops) then you can use a combo box, and set limit to list = yes. That way, the user can type in the text, and access will "auto complete", or the user can use the drop down combo. And you get free verification also. However, if the item table is large (say > 2000 rows), then a combo box becomes less then a ideal user interface option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Dcount` function to validate the input. See below

```
Dim userInput as string
userInput = "B8631" 

If Dcount("*","Item_Master","Primal_Code='" & userInput & "'")<=0 Then
    msgbox "not found"
    exit sub        
end if
```